# Passing the "continue" content of the wikipedia API gives me a badcontinue error

Tags: python, json, wikipedia-api, continue

I'm trying to build a loop that gives me all the pageids of a category. Thus, I'm trying to use the "continue" parameter as intended.

Here is the initialization with a first query that is working :

```py
import requests
URL = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

PARAMS_FRANCE = {
        "action": "query",
        "cmtitle": 'Catégorie:Portail:France/Articles liés',
        "list": "categorymembers",
        "cmlimit": 500,
        "format": "json"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS_FRANCE)
DATA = R.json()
PAGES_FRANCE = DATA['query']['categorymembers']
idx_continue = DATA['continue']
```

But then, when it enters the loop :

```py
while('continue' in DATA):
    PARAMS_FRANCE = {
        "action": "query",
        "cmtitle": 'Catégorie:Portail:France/Articles liés',
        "list": "categorymembers",
        "cmlimit": 500,
        "continue": idx_continue,
        "format": "json"
    }

    R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS_FRANCE)
    DATA = R.json()
    PAGES_FRANCE = DATA['query']['categorymembers']
    idx_continue = DATA['continue']
```

It returns me the following error when I print `DATA`:

```json
{
   "error":{
      "code":"badcontinue",
      "info":"Invalid continue param. You should pass the original value returned by the previous query.",
      "*":"See https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&amp;gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
   },
   "servedby":"mw1390"
}
```

Except I gave all the content of `continue` so what could be the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: you never update the value of the `idx_continue` variable, so it fails the second time around

Comment: Indeed, but it should not be a problem ? It doesn't solve the problem since it fails the first time in the loop. But thank you for pointing out I'm editing this.

Comment: I think you need `DATA["continue"]["continue"]`, from the looks of it

Comment: (or use `cmcontinue` and use `DATA["continue"["cmcontinue"]`, I'm not sure which should be used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use the continuation parameters is to merge them with the original parameters (ie. `PARAMS_FRANCE.update(DATA['continue'])`).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I was trying to fetch the backlinks. I changed a little bit of your code, the setting of the parameters, like this:

```
PARAMS_RUSSIA2 = {
    "action": "query",
    "bltitle": 'Russia',
    "list": "backlinks",
    "bllimit": 500,
    "blcontinue": idx_continue['blcontinue'],
    "continue":idx_continue['continue'],
    "format": "json"
}
```

In this way, I can get the second 500 results:)

Comment: When I put it in the loop, it seems that I can still get all the results, but the final round did not have the parameter 'continue', so there will be an error..